# .NET Scanning API for 64bit machine

Tags: c#, scanning, twain

Is there a .Net scanning API available for 64bit machine to scan document or images from scanner? Can anyone give me sample code for this.

Thanks 
Asif

Comment: Scanning API for? searching system or Scanning images with devices?

Comment: What do you intend to scan? The pc, hearts, lungs, brains?

Comment: I have updated my question please check now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running a scanning app on a 64-bit machine via ClickOnce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287492/running-a-scanning-app-on-a-64-bit-machine-via-clickonce)

Comment: here is an article about [.NET scanning component](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/432808/Document-Processing-SDK-for-NET)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely have an 'x86' (32-bit) reference in your project, for example DotTwain. 'Any CPU' means that the .NET framework will run it as 'x64' because you've told it anything is OK. Then it tries to load a reference, finds it's 32-bit and gives a 'BadImageFormatException' (usually).

Answer (score 4):

We used leadtools sdk for a similar requirement. They do have a 64 bit version, but we actually found that many hardware manufacturers didn’t provide a 64 bit driver. Maybe that has changed since last time we checked. We used this  [Tutorial](http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/dh/tw/leadtools.twain~leadtools.twain.twainsession~acquire.html) to get started.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I did not looked the tags. 
Open source /free, best known TWAIN API is already mentioned by another user. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1376/NET-TWAIN-image-scanner

However the best paid TWAIN component for web and desktop environment is available at following URL by Atalasoft.

[Atalasoft TWAIN Scanning SDK](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/dottwain)

It is very flexible, fast and reliable..  I have used it for years.

Answer (score 1):

You could use either WIA (Windows Image Acquisition) or TWAIN via DllImport.

Here is an example of WIA: http://miljenkobarbir.com/using-a-scanner-without-dialogs-in-net/
That post contains plenty of comments to help you understand it.

Here is a Code Project article on using TWAIN: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1376/NET-TWAIN-image-scanner

Answer (score 0):

Unlike many other libraries, [Asprise C# VB.NET Scanning & Imaging SDK for TWAIN scanners](http://asprise.com/c%23-vb.net-scanner-api/twain-wia-scan-pdf-library-overview.html) works for both 64bit and 32bit applications. By default, almost all vendors supply 32bit TWAIN drivers only, thus most scanners will not show up in 64bit environments.

> Asprise Scanning SDK is probably the only scanning library that works
>   for both 64bit and 32bit applications thanks to our innovative patent
>   pending technology and quality implementation.

[image]

- *Disclaimer: I work for Asprise*